# Can Eclipse be convinced to line-wrap comments in C++?

Tags: eclipse

```
// I am sick of having to insert line breaks when
// my comments reach 80 characters.
```

Ctrl+Shift+F doesn't wrap the comments.

Any clues?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems it is not possible. A shame, really.

Source: this mail from the CDT mailing list, dating April 2011 : http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/cdt-dev/msg21675.html

EDIT (March 2013)

It now seems possible, but only for `/* this kind of comments */`.
Set the desired width in the formatter options, and trigger by
selecting your comment and pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd>.

Comment: Yep, that's the conclusion I came to as well.

Comment: I have comment line length set by default to 80, multi-line comment as you wrote, but automatic code format (Ctrl + Shift + F) doesn't break these lines. What should I do? I have Eclipse 3.8. Oh, and I'm using Java, don't know if it is relevant.

Comment: @line reformatting has always worked for me in Java (unlike in C++, which is my current predicament).

Comment: @regardl I think I must just don't have one of the checkboxes on the very top than (this comment is pretty old... ;)) - now it also works file for me.

Answer (score -2):

It is possible, but tricky

In your new code style profile, set "Maximum line width" from 80 to 1000.

Eclipse will not allow you modifying existing code style profile, you have to create new one.

Comment: I think you misunderstand: I _want_ my comments to wrap.